# i cannot understand this statement (multi dimensional array)

Tags: python

In a piece of code I am trying to understand, I encounter the following statement:

```
_RecvBuf[conn] = _RecvBuf[conn][8+msgSize:]
```

_RecvBuf is declared as

```
_RecvBuf = {}
```

and msgSize is an integer. I fail to see what this means, any help?

Comment: This doesn't sound right.  There are no declarations in Python, and `_RecvBuf{}` isn't valid.

Comment: Please consider [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for some of your previous questions; those where your problem has been solved, which you indicated in the comments. This rewards both you and the answerer (who is helping you for free) with some reputation and indicates to the wider community that your problem has been solved. It also will make people more willing to help you in the future.

Comment: my mistake, there should be an '=' in between

Comment: @Ben of course, I'll check it right away. I have looked for this, any time I see 'was this useful to you' I have answered it. I will check again and accept the answers I have received in the past since I am really grateful for the way issues get solved here.

Comment: @Ben I have accepted some answers, there is a problem though that some of the right answers are given as a comment to the original question. In this you cannot accept it, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

_RecvBuf is a dictionary, and it looks like it maps connections to strings.  In which case, `_RecvBuf[conn]` is a string, and `_RecvBuf[conn] = _RecvBuf[conn][8+msgSize:]` will chop off the first `8+msgSize` bytes from conn's string.

Python uses [] syntax both for finding keys in dictionaries, and for slicing strings.